# if statement evaluates incorrectly

Tags: javascript

```
function ipsBetween(start, end){
    var count = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      if(start.split('.').slice(i, i + 1) != end.split('.').slice(i, i + 1)) {
       count++;
      }
    }
    return count;
}
```

I am trying to find all possible IP's between a range. The above code is just a starting. I was trying to split the IP in pieces and check if they are equal or not. While I was doing so, interesingly even if the values are equal it evaluates the **if** statement as true and increases the count. Here is my test case:

> ipsBetween("10.0.0.0", "10.0.0.50")

This test case returns 4, whereas it should return 1. I don't know why this is happening. I implicity looked the values of **start.split('.').slice(i, i + 1)** and **end.split('.').slice(i, i + 1)** and the first three element is seem to be equal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's really no need to use `.slice()` here. (That's what's causing the problem: `.slice()` returns an array, and two different arrays will never be equal to each other.) Split the strings first and then just use array indexing:

```
var count = 0;
start = start.split("."); end = end.split(".");
for (var i = 0; i < start.length; ++i)
  if (start[i] != end[i])
    count++;
return count;
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that operator `!=` when comparing two list objects will return `true` if they're not the very same object: `split` returns a list of strings but `slice(i, i+1)` will return a list of length 1.

This means that you're comparing `["10"]` with another `["10"]` and they're two different list objects, so `!=` will return true.

If you just compare the contents using `x.slice(".")[i]` instead of using `slice` then the result is what you were expecting.

PS: The operator `!=` of Javascript is terrible and you should not use it and prefer instead `!==`. It would be the same in this case, but it's much nicer to work with because it doesn't do crazy things when the two types are different.

PS2: Seems a good idea to split the strings at each iteration?

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing `arrays` not `strings` you want to compare the `string` values try this instead:

```
function ipsBetween(start, end){
    var count = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      if(start.split('.').slice(i, i + 1)[0] != end.split('.').slice(i, i + 1)[0]) {
       count++;
      }
    }
    return count;
}
console.log(ipsBetween("10.0.0.0", "10.0.0.50"));
```

The problem is the array objects returned won't equal each other because they are not the same array ie. they are not located at the same spot in memory...